# Merge and overwrite features between 2 shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, spatial-join, update

I have 2 polygon shapefiles with similar features. One shapefile is "the master" (masterFile) and the other is a subset of features from the masterFile with some of those features slightly changed and/or a few new features added (subFile). I want to use the subsetFile to update the masterFile polygons.

What is the simplest way to do this?

I have already tried Merge and Spatial Join (perhaps I used them incorrectly), but the masterFile features that I wanted changed to the subsetFile features were not changed.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Overlay Toolset?

Comment: Delete from master and append or merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Union tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) instead of the Spatial Join or Merge tools. Union tool will replace the existing feature in the Master file with the subset file. However, you may still need to do some post processing clean the final output if necessary.

This is a screenshot from the help above.

[image]